# Verify that this is not orientable.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Verify that this is not orientable.

Möbius transformation:

$$U=\{(t,\theta) \mid \frac{-1}{2}\lt t\lt \frac{1}{2}, 0\lt \theta \lt 2\pi \}$$
$\sigma (t, \theta)=<((1-t\sin (\theta/2))\cos (\theta), (1-t\sin (\theta/2)\sin \theta, t \cos (\theta /2)>$

$\tilde{U}=\{(t,\theta) \mid \frac{-1}{2}\lt t\lt \frac{1}{2}, -\pi\lt \theta \lt \pi \}$
$$\tilde{\sigma}(t,\theta)=\sigma(t, \theta) $$

$\{\sigma, \tilde{\sigma}\}$ forms an atlas for möbius band

$$N_{\sigma}=\lambda (t,\theta)N_{\tilde{\sigma}}$$

---

I have written all I know. Please help me to verify that this is not orientable.

And also I calculated the following:

$\sigma_{\theta}=(-\sin \theta, \cos \theta, 0)$

and $\sigma_t=(-\sin (\theta /2)\cos \theta, -\sin (\theta /2)\sin \theta, \cos (\theta /2)$

and $\sigma_t \times \sigma_{\theta}=(-\cos \theta \cos (\theta /2), -\sin \theta cos(\theta /2), -\sin (\theta/2))$

$N_{\sigma}=\sigma_t \times \sigma_{\theta}$

But I dont understand why the möbius band is not orientable.

[image]

Comment: What does you have to do in order to prove that this surface is not orientable?

Comment: I dont know this. There is some information, but I cannot understand enough. So I have asked here @Tomás

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** A hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is orientable if, and only if there is a global, smooth, unit length normal vector field.

Comment: Dear Nicoud, I calculated $\sigma_{\theta}=(-\sin \theta, \cos \theta, 0)$ and $\sigma_t=(-\sin (\theta /2)\cos \theta, -\sin (\theta /2)\sin \theta, \cos (\theta /2)$ and $\sigma_t \times \sigma_{\theta}=(-\cos \theta \cos (\theta /2), -\sin \theta cos(\theta /2), -\sin (\theta/2))$

Comment: I get $N_{\sigma}=\sigma_t \times \sigma_{\theta}$

Comment: But I cannot understand why the mobius band is not orientable. I have an explanation about this. But I cannot see the reason. If I post the explanation, can you show?

Comment: The reason is that if you take a unit normal vector and make it go around the strip, after one complete turn it will be turned upside down.